# iOS: App installed on device can't be found via the search feature

Tags: iphone, ios, applications

I've got an iPhone 8 running iOS 12.3.1 (latest as of writing).

Recently I've noticed that when I search for an app that is already installed on my iPhone by using the built-in search feature, the app is not found.

The only way I can locate the app is by either manually find it in a folder, or by going to the App Store, searching for it there, then tapping **Open**.

The app in question is 1Password.

Any idea why the app can't be found? Does it have to do with caching? And if so, how can I clear the cache?

Comment: What is the name of the app displayed below the app icon? On the App Store? What is the search string that you are typing?

Comment: @NimeshNeema see updated question

Comment: Go to Settings app → Siri & Search → 1Password and check if Siri & Suggestions and Show App is turned off? If yes, turn them on and try again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to Settings app → Siri & Search → 1Password and check if Siri & Suggestions is turned off. If yes, turn it on.

[image]

Now, the app should appear in search results in Spotlight search.